# Pyspark: transform categorial column into a binary array

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe where there is a column where each value is a string, and i wish to transform it such that each appearance of a string for the specific id (represented in a different column) would serve as a one in the array in the appropriate location. As an example if i have this dataset:

```
category   id
a          1
b          1
c          1
a          2
d          2
```

I wish to transform it into:

```
id   result
1    [1,1,1,0]
2    [1,0,0,1]
```

Any idea on how to do this?

EDIT: i tried using the string indexer but all it did was count the amount of appearences up when i really wanted to get the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can first pivot and fill null with 0 then convert the columns apart from the `id` column to an array:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

res = df.groupBy('id').pivot("category").agg(F.count("category")).fillna(0)
res.select("id",F.array(*[F.col(i) for i in res.columns[1:]]).alias("result")).show()
```

---

```
+---+------------+
| id|      result|
+---+------------+
|  1|[1, 1, 1, 0]|
|  2|[1, 0, 0, 1]|
+---+------------+
```

Note that if elements can repeat, you can have counts more than 1 in which case you can add a when+otherwise:

```
(res.select("id",F.array(*[F.when(F.col(i)>=1,1).otherwise(0) 
                       for i in res.columns[1:]]).alias("result"))).show()
```